# How to log a list of elements length?

Tags: javascript, cypress

This code logs nothing for me. Why?

```
  const items = cy.get('[role="cell"]');
  let length = items.its('length');
  cy.log('length', length)
  cy.log('length = ${length}.');
  cy.log('length = ${items.length}.');
```

Actual log:

```
loglength, {specwindow: <window>, chainerid: ch-https://192.168.51.12:8080-14}

loglength = ${length}.

loglength = ${items.length}.
```

Comment: you are not using the right method to retrieve the length of the elements.

Comment: `cy.get()` is an asynchronous command

Comment: Can you tell me please how to do that right?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].